# calling rest api from angular js using $resource?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I am new to AngularJS. I want to call rest api from angular js using $resource.But not able to get it right.**

**This is index.html**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <script src="./angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="./controllers.js"></script>
     <script src="./angular-resource.js"></script>
     <script src="./services.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="loginController">
        <h1>  try to call restapi </h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

**this is controller.js**

```
var myapp=angular.module('myApp', ['user']);
myapp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', 'loginUser',
function ($scope, loginUser) {

 alert(loginUser.login());
}]);
```

**this is service.js**

```
angular.module('user', ['ngResource']).

config(function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = "application/json";
}).factory('loginUser', function($resource){

   return $resource('http://localhost/testtext/index.php/user/login',{
   login: {method:'POST', params:{"email":"prashant@gmail.com","password":"weldone"}, isArray:false}

        });

});
```

**Actually params json is not going in proper Format,due to that I am getting this error on console.**

```
POST http://localhost/testtext/index.php/user/login?  email=prashant%40gmailcom&password=weldone 500 (PHP Error) angular.min.js:99
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:99
n angular.min.js:95
l angular.min.js:94
Resource.(anonymous function) angular-resource.js:469
(anonymous function) controllers.js:6
d angular.min.js:28
instantiate angular.min.js:28
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:52
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:43
m angular.min.js:6
i angular.min.js:43
e angular.min.js:39
e angular.min.js:39
e angular.min.js:39
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:38
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:16
e.$eval angular.min.js:88
e.$apply angular.min.js:88
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:16
d angular.min.js:27
c angular.min.js:16
rb angular.min.js:16
jc angular.min.js:15
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:163
a angular.min.js:117
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:23
m angular.min.js:6
c
```

Comment: Things don't look terribly wrong. The error you are getting is a 500 [Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) from the server trying to respond to your post. The angular looks ok at first glance. Try using a tool like [Advanced Rest Client (Chrome)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) to get the post right, then make sure your request matches that.

Comment: @fooby is this code  correct from angular side?

Comment: @fooby I am not sure how to send params in POST?It may be the problem?

Comment: The service looks ok based on one I have written and on the documentation on [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource). Do you want to send the params in the URL? Or, do you want to send it as postData? If it's supposed to be POST Data, then it might explain your 500 Server Error. Please, take a look at the Advanced Rest Client I linked to above. It will help you better understand how REST services work with URLs and POST data. Then, you can check the browsers console to see what it is actually sending(F12 on most browsers).

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the angular looks ok but perhaps it is not sending the data in the correct format for your php service. I had to do the following for a service that was expecting form-encoded data. Hopefully it (or something similar) will work for you.

```
     $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'rest/mm/login',
         data: 'username=' + $scope.username + "&password=" + $scope.password,
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
     }).success(function (result) {
         authService.loginConfirmed(result);
     });
```

(clearly the username/password should be url encoded for safety etc)